# Can not start Oracle database 11g XE on Ubuntu 64bit

Tags: software-installation

I can not start Oracle on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

After trying to configure:

`sudo` / `etc` / `init.d` / `oracle-xe configure`

This error appears:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition is not configured.  You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database"
```

I have logged in as root and then run the script successfully configured.